# Pycharm Scientific Mode: deactivate "Run with Python Console"

Tags: python, pycharm

When I activate Scientific Mode in Pycharm, then run some python scripts and then deactivate Scientific mode again, sometimes some python scripts still have "Run with python console" activated (when I run them again). Expected behaviour would be that these scripts would run in the normal "[Run tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-tool-window.html)".
I have to uncheck "Run with python console" manually to get the expected behavior:
Rightclick somewhere in the script -> More Run/Debug -> Modify Run Configuration -> Run with Python Console.

How can be "Run with Python Console" automatically turned off after deactivating Scientific mode?

Pycharm Version: 2022.2.3 (Professional Edition)
OS: Windows 10 Pro

Here is a screenshot of the "Run with Python Console" setting:
[image]

Comment: hI please list out the pycharm version, your OS, and professional or community edition?